# What is single crystal?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

What is single crystal ? Is it made up with different atoms with the same orientation or it must be the same atom ?

Sorry but our professor couldn’t explain it well :(

Here is a picture of a single crystal and he said “ the different colors for clarification but single crystal must made with the same atom”. 
[image]

Comment: Your instructor is wrong- single crystals can be made out of dissimilar atoms- salt is a perfect example (sodium and chlorine ions), silica is another (silicon and oxygen).

Comment: Thank you , i was really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A single-crystal, or monocrystalline, solid is a material in which the crystal lattice of the entire sample is continuous and unbroken to the edges of the sample, with no grain boundaries.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_crystal)

Answer (score 0):

Such crystal in which orientation of plane is identical through out the lattice called single crystal.